# Time Format JavaScript

Tags: javascript, datetime, time

const currentDate = new Date();

console.log(currentDate.toLocaleString())
output:
9/5/2022, 8:03:03 PM

but I need this format:
9/22 8:03 PM -> Month/YY H:MM AM/PM, no ','(comma)

Can someone help me please ?

Comment: Try manually combining `.toLocaleTimeString()` and `.toLocaleDateString()`

Comment: Why not just remove the comma then?

Comment: What have you tried so far? What problems have you faced?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get your specified time format, you can pass in options to the `toLocaleString()` and then remove the comma manually.

You can read more about date time format options at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleString

```js
const currentDate = new Date();
const options = {
    month: 'numeric',
    year: '2-digit',
    hour: 'numeric',
    minute: '2-digit',
};
const dateString = currentDate.toLocaleString('en-us', options).replace(',', '');
console.log(dateString);
```